# do not undsrstand file structure of pgsql

Tags: postgresql

Can someone provide a bit of clarification?

I understand that the /base folder show a data folder for each database.  In PgAdmin, I have 13 databases listed under 1 server.  In the /base folder, there are 14 folders.  So that should be 1 per database and 1 for the the server equalling 14. 
I do not know how do know what folder is for what database.  However, only one has a lot of data.  When I search for large files on my system, this displays:

```
16M: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/18642/18652
13M: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/18642/18751
1.0G: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/21719/21804
12M: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/21719/21806
15M: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/21719/21750
20M: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/21719/21837
118M: /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/base/21719/21834
```

Now, if this is (21719) actually the only running database used by staff, when I archive (pgdump) it, the size of the dump is approx 6 Gig.  The size of the dump and the data listed above do not match.

Can someone shed some light on my confusion?

Thanks a bunch.

This was a result of trying to find out why I have almost 700 gig of drive space being used when the only stuff on it is postgresql and an occasional runaway vnc-error-log that eats up drive space (figured out how to solve that).  However, I still have over 60% of my drive used, I cannot account for it, and found the data sizes in postgresql.

Thanks for any insight that can be provided on postgresql db data

Comment: My guess is that the dump is in a more verbose format (perhaps as SQL commands) so that it can be read easily, whereas the actual data is very compact. This would account for the discrepancy in file size.

Comment: Keep in mind that Postgres also has a feature called [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/storage-toast.html), which can compress data on the heap table.  6 gigs of text could easily be 1 gig on disk.

Comment: You could take a look at the contents of the dump. Basically it is just a tar file with all the scripts and table data plus a TOC. If the data is uncompressed, an inflation factor of 5..10 would not be too surprising. If the *kolmogorov complexity* of the data is high, compression would not lead to significant size reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know how do know what folder is for what database

The folder name is the OID of the database, which you can get with the following SQL query, along with each db size according to the SQL engine:

```
select oid,datname,pg_database_size(datname) from pg_database;
```

If there are 13 databases and 14 folders, the additional folder is probably the `pgsql_tmp` directory used for temporary files. The concept of `server` of pgAdmin does not come into play in a specific server's data directory.

Also as said in the comments, the dump size may be greater than the disk size due compression. It can also be smaller since it doesn't contain any index data. On the whole, knowing the size on disk does not help much to predict the size of the SQL dump and vice versa.